# Return two decimal points in create function

Tags: sql

I have here an sql create function that will return float datatype.
I would like to know if how am I going to show the results to two decimal points.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_get_total] 
(
-- Add the parameters for the function here
@code as int
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
 -- Declare the return variable here
 DECLARE @quantity as FLOAT
 DECLARE @price as FLOAT

    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
 SET @quantity =  (SELECT quantity FROM Requested_Item where Code_id = @code)
SET @price = (SELECT price FROM Requested_Item where Code_id = @code)
-- Return the result of the function
RETURN @quantity * @price

END
```

The sample results:

```
1632.1740985705144
6323.8092596543638
```

Comment: So do you want the results to be `1632.17` and `6323.80`?

Comment: @Aishvarya Karthik, yes definitely.

Comment: Check my answer below, if it works. Please upvote if it does.

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik, yeah it works, I just only applied it in the return statement because same thing happened when I tried to cast the float column. Thanks for this.

Comment: Glad to help. Please upvote/accept helpful answers.

Comment: I'm not yet allowed to upvote answers. I will do once allowed.

Comment: Please tag dbms! (Non-ANSI SQL here...)

Answer (score 1):

Use `CAST`

```
select cast(float_column as decimal(10,2))
from your_table
```

`decimal(10,2)` will display 10 digits before the point and 2 after it.

Comment: Actually, it will display maximum 8 digits before the decimal and 2 after the decimal

Answer (score 1):

First of all. I'd rewrite your function. You're querying your table twice. This can be done by running a single SELECT statement. See this code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_get_total]
(
    @code AS INT
)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @quantity AS FLOAT
        , @price AS FLOAT;

    SELECT @quantity = quantity, @price = price
    FROM Requested_Item
    WHERE Code_id = @code;

    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @quantity * @price;
END
```

Now how to format your numbers properly? I used this method with `CEILING` and a bit of maths:

```
DECLARE @first FLOAT = 1632.1740985705144
  , @second FLOAT = 6323.8092596543638;


SELECT FLOOR(@first * 100) / 100
  , FLOOR(@second * 100) / 100;
```

It brings requested result:

```
╔═════════╦════════╗
║ 1632.17 ║ 6323.8 ║
╚═════════╩════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RETURN TRUNCATE(@quantity * @price, 2)
```

The 2 at the end means there will be 2 decimal points. You can really use the `TRUNCATE` function anywhere - the only downside is that it doesn't really round the numbers.

Comment: it says there `RETURN statements in scalar valued functions must include an argument.
`

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the return statement of my function to

`RETURN CAST ((@total / @cur_amount) as decimal(10,2))`

and it shows the 2 decimal points.